# Is there Conditional Formatting or a formula that can copy rows from my main report sheet to different sheets based on multiple criteria?

Tags: excel

So, I've tried to troubleshoot and I've Googled everywhere to help me figure this out. I need a formula or formatting to copy rows from my main report sheets to different sheets based on multiple criteria.

Here's an overview of my report page and the different sheets I need rows copied into based on my criteria.

[image]

Example #1:

So if **Ref: Delivery Appointment Date Late** contains 00:00, and **Target Delivery (Late)** is in the past or equal to the current date, the whole row needs copied to **Del. Appt None past Target** sheet.

Example #2:

If **Ref: Delivery Appointment Date Late** contains 00:00, and **Target Delivery (Late)** is in the future, the whole row needs copied to Del. Appt None sheet.

And basically, I need a formula that I can work with to match criteria for the remaining sheets with similar situations.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm a beginner with Excel, and I've tried everything I've Googled but I can't get anything to work the way I need it to.

Comment: If you have Excel 365 you can use the `FILTER`-function.

Answer (score 0):

```
=FILTER(Table1,(Table1[Target Delivery (Late)]<=NOW())*(LEN(Table1[Ref: Delivery Appointment Date Late])<>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Table1[Ref: Delivery Appointment Date Late],"00:00",""))))
```

The formula above would return the table (I've named it Table1) filtered down to the conditions you listed in example 1. A similar formula could be constructed for all your other conditions.

Also, I only have the snapshot of your data, so it's hard to tell how the dates are being stored. If the Target Delivery (Late) column is stored as text, you might have to wrap that part in a `DateValue` function.